# Simple OpenGL shader gives an error in LibGDX (no uniform with name diffuseTexture)

Tags: java, opengl, shader, libgdx

I don't understand why when building I get an error when setting this simple shader to an imported mesh (.obj mesh), the error I get is:
"no uniform with name 'diffuseTexture' in shader"

The thing is, I don't want to use a texture at the moment, for learning purposes I wanted to start simply by having a red mesh, and going step by step from there..

Here's some code too:

```
ObjLoader loader = new ObjLoader();
model = loader.loadObj(Gdx.files.internal("model.obj"),true);

String vertexShader = "" +
"attribute vec4 Position;" +
"uniform mat4 u_projView;" +
"void main() {" +
"gl_Position = u_projView * Position;" +
"}";

String fragmentShader = "void main() {" +
"gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);" +
"}";

ShaderProgram shader = new ShaderProgram(vertexShader,fragmentShader);

model.render(shader);
```

Errors I get:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application"
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no uniform with name
'diffuseTexture' in shader  at
com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:113)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no uniform with name
'diffuseTexture' in shader  at
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram.fetchUniformLocation(ShaderProgram.java:283)
    at
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram.setUniformi(ShaderProgram.java:297)
    at
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.materials.TextureAttribute.bind(TextureAttribute.java:80)
    at
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.materials.Material.bind(Material.java:70)
    at
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.model.still.StillModel.render(StillModel.java:57)
```

Comment: Where's your [`model.setMaterials()`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/model/still/StillModel.html#render%28com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram%29) call?

Comment: @genpfault I haven't seen even one tutorial with that, I did try it on my own earlier today and it took away the error but the mesh wasnt displayed at all.

Comment: Did the "no uniform" error come with a stack trace?

Comment: @genpfault Yeah, I edited the question and added some of it

Comment: "*I don't want to use a texture at the moment*" LibGDX wants to. And since it's in charge, you're going to have to either use a texture or find a way to placate it.

Comment: @NicolBolas I tried to use one and I still have problems, the model appears white for one second and disappears, even when applying a material and calling texture.bind() before rendering

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the source code of libGDX, I can assume that your **model.obj** has a texture assigned to it in material section. So GDX creates material with a texture attribute and tries to set it.

What you may try to do is:

- use OBJ model without texture
- call Material::removeAttribute() with a texture attribute
- add "sampler2D diffuseTexture" string to your shader, but be sure to use it somehow, or else, this attribute will be removed from your shader. You may do it e.g. like this:

  ```
  vec4 texval = texture2d(diffuseTexture, vec2(0,0));
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) + texval*0;
  ```